# Clear url after submit

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, url, redux

I'm using react, redux and react-router in my application. When I submit login and password I post axios request to my backend and then update my user after I get a response. This works fine, but my problem is that after i press Enter or click "Login" my url change to something like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/?email=example123%40gmail.com&password=pass123
```

Is there any way to prevent url from changing or to clear it after submit?

Form:

```
 <form onSubmit={this.login}>      
        <div className="loginForm">
        <label> Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" onChange={this.handleChange} />     
        <div className="loginError">{this.state.emailErr}</div>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input  type="password" name="password" onChange={this.handleChange} />        
        <div className="loginError">{this.state.pswdErr}</div>
        <span style={{paddingTop: "30px"}}/>
        <button style={{width: "100%"}} type="submit" >Login </button>         
        </div>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form is trying to submit itself by default.
Add this to your login method:

```
login(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Of coure, just need to wait 10 minutes